# Selecting from two tables with a same named column

Tags: sql, standards

`SELECT bar.*, baz.foo FROM bar LEFT JOIN baz` if I have a column called foo in bar, what is the standard SQL behaviour? Will the result set contain only foo from baz or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will contain column `foo` from both tables.

Since your question is tagged 'standards', I would suggest using an explicit alias for 2 columns with the same name in a result set.

Comment: +1 Additionally, atleast in case of Oracle - dunno if there is any standard on this but the column from table `baz` has an autogenerated alias - on the lines of `foo_1`

Answer (score 0):

It will contain two output columns called `foo`; one with values from table `bar` and one values from table `baz`.

If you do a natural join, then the `foo` columns will be used in the join and only one value will appear in the output - but you did a left outer join, not a natural join.

You do need to specify the join condition with an ON clause or a USING clause (but not every DBMS supports USING).

Answer (score 0):

It will contain 2 x foo columns. This isn't a problem for SQL, but it tends to break client code. Simply alias it

```
SELECT bar.*, baz.foo AS foo2...
SELECT bar.*, foo2 = baz.foo...
```

While we're on standards, `SELECT *` isn't good practice: use named columns. It's been discussed to death already in other questions...